# How to explain my code with scanf()?

Tags: c

I'm a newbie in C programming and I'm learning the `scanf` now.

I wrote some code and I'm trying to understand it.

Here is the code:

```
 #include <studio.h>
 int main(){
    int a=1, b=2, c=3;
    scanf ("%d%d", &a,&b); 
    scanf ("%d", &c); 
    scanf ("%d", &c); 
    printf ("a=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d\n", a, b, c); 
    return 0; 
 }

When I input 
11 22 33 44
The output is 
a=11
b=22
c=44
```

This is normal. However, when I input:

```
11, 22, 33, 44
Output
a=11
b=2
c=3
```

It looks like the commas stops the input process.

Who can explain to me why is this happening?

Actually, when putting the commas between `%d%d` (it is like "`%d, %d"`), and providing input data, the input have to be separated with commas.

Who can give me some suggestions for commas in `scanf` parameters?

Comment: `scanf` tries to interpret the input as specified by you. That works fine for the first `%d`, which is obviously 11. Then it reads a `,` and tries to convert it into a integer, which does not work. So it fails and the value is same one as before (`b=2`).
The next `scanf` tries the same and fails again, thus having `c=3`.
So just don't separate your values with a `,` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Rather than trying to guess at how `scanf()` behaves, how about reading its documentation or its explanation in whatever text you're using?  Or maybe asking your instructor?  We expect you to make a reasonable effort to find a solution for yourself before asking for help here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I learn C by myself, and no instructor can help me.

Comment: `man scanf` - it works for all `c` functions BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf stop reading when find a character in stdin that doesn't matches the format string.

In your example, your scanf expect only character that forms an integer value. Infact, the first scanf stops when it reaches the first comma. When the other scanfs try to read in the stdin, the first character they will find will be the last character the previuos scanf read but didn't use, the comma. This is the reason why they will end soon without read anything.

If you want to use commas or other character in your input over the values you want to memorize, you have to insert them explicity in the format string.

For example with this statment:

```
    scanf("%d, %d", &a, &b);
```

You are instructing the scanf to read an integer and save it in the variable a, read a comma and forget it, then read another integer and save it in the variable b. If during the parsing the scanf will find something that it is not an integer or a comma they will stop immediately without reads other values(this is the reason why b and c have the earlier value in your program).

Answer (score 0):

you can use commas in `scanf` like this :
`scanf ("%d,%d,%d", &a,&b,&c);`
then you input numbers in single line seperated with commas.
`11,12,13`.
Note that in this scenario `scanf` expects single line input of numbers seperated with commas. If your input in this case will be `11 12 13` then You will now get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guys reply. I tried another code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=1, b=2, c=3;
    scanf ("%d, %d", &a,&b); 
    scanf ("%d", &c); 
    scanf ("%d", &c); 
    printf ("a=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d\n", a, b, c); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When i input

```
11 22 33 44
```

output:

```
a=11
b=2
c=33
```

how to explain?

Comment: This answers does not answer the issues of the post, but is another question.  Recommend removal.

Answer (score 0):

To second question ( do not know how to quote here :( )

First `scanf` expects integers seperated with commas. As you did not enter your inputs like that that `scanf` took first number `11` and assigned it to `a` (`b` is ignored). Second `scanf` took number `22` and third `scanf` number `33`. Number `44` in the input is redundant. Thats why your output looks like that. 
Note that `b=2` is from previous part of code `int b=2`